# How to execute something after finishing map function?

Tags: javascript

I want to execute something after finishing the map function.

1. I thought we could use the callback function as follows. But it doesn't exist, so it didn't work:

   ```
   this.data.map((v, i) => {
       console.log("in map func");
   }, () => {
      console.log("callback of map");             
   });
   ```
2. So I changed it like this

   ```
   var last = this.data.length;

   this.data.map((v, i) => {
       console.log("in map func");
       if(i + 1 === last) {
           console.log("last!!");
       }
   });
   ```

It worked, but if someone knows a better way, tell me please.

**ADD**

```
this.data.map((v, i) => {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("in map"); }, 3000);
});

console.log("after map");
```

↑ "after map" shows at first on this code.
  (my purpose is using ajax in map func)

Comment: Why do you want that to be executed *as part* of executing `.map`? Makes more sense to me to just have the extra operation after the `.map` call.

Comment: There is the concept of a statement in JavaScript. Just add a new statement. What's more, you are misusing `map` here, as apparently there is no mapping happening. Use `forEach`.

Comment: Just  to be clear, you are talking about `Array.prototype.map()` correct?  This is not some asynchronous function that deals with mapping Web requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to run a command right after your `map` you simply can put it in next line of your code :

```
this.data.map((v, i) => {
   // Do whatever you want to do
});
console.log("This will run after your map is done");
```

To understand this even easier, since `map` will return a new object, you can do :

```
var myArray = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);
console.log(map1); // This will have the final result of map
```

UPDATE :

So your question was not really clear, now I think understand what do you want to do, I think you can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      this.data.map((v, i) => {
        setTimeout(function(){ resolve('in map'); }, 3000);
       });
});

 promise1.then(function(value) {
     console.log(value);
     // expected output: "in map"
 });
```

Comment: @kazon I update the answer, not sure why you want to use setTimeout, but I guess Promise is what you need